# ILoggerFactory could not be found after adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides

Tags: asp.net-core

After adding this dependency

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

to my project.json file for a asp.net core project, the type ILoggerFactory can not longer be resolved. I get a compile error saying "The type or namespace name 'ILoggerFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I did not change anything else than just adding this reference. I find this very strange.

Any suggestions how this can happen?

Comment: Post your whole project.json or the according framework/dependencies sections. Sounds like you are mixing rc1 and rc2 in one project

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I'm mixing rc1 and rc2. The error message is not very obvious.